# Geb Modules showing an error

Tags: intellij-idea, geb

I'm working on a geb page object with a repeating set of UI elements a div container with a text input and button within.

I am attempting the following:

```
class MyModule extends Module{
  static content = {
    textInput {$("input.editTextField")}
    removeInputButton {$("button.removeButton")}
  }
}

class MyPage extends Page{
  static content = {
    myInputs { index ->
      $("div.container", index).module(MyModule)
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ the code is highlighted in MyPage on ("div.container, index) when I hover over this I see "'$' in 'geb.Page' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String.?)'

My goal is to be able pick an iteration of the UI and to perform something like:

```
myInputs(0).textInput = 'foo'
myInputs(1).textInput = 'bar'
myInputs(5).removeInputButton.click()
```

I've referred to the documentation for Geb but by all accounts this should work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exception do you get when you run your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, it's just that your code is not type safe enough for IntelliJ to know which method you're calling. If you change your content definition to:

```
myInputs { int index ->
    $("div.container", index).module(MyModule)
}
```

then the warning will disappear.